# Как убрать часть (расширение файла) из строки?

Tags: c#, переменные

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string buf = textBox1.Text; //buffer 1
        string buf2 = textBox2.Text; //buffer 2
        string fn = (textBox3.Text + ".txt"); //file name

        File.AppendAllText(fn, "────────────────────────" + "\n\n" + buf + "\n" + buf2 + "\n\n"); //AppendAllText best choise for this // WriteAllText // Create

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fn);
        //string text = (sr.ReadToEnd());
        //listBox1.Items.Clear();
        //listBox1.Items.Add(text);
        string text;
        while ((text = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(text);
            //string[] It = new string[10];
            //for (int i = 0; i < It.Length; i++) listBox1.Items.Add((text + i).ToString());
            //text += 10;
        }
        sr.Close();
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;

        File.WriteAllText("config.conf", fn);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //config initialisation
        //File.Create("config.conf");
        StreamReader lr = new StreamReader("config.conf");
        string text = lr.ReadLine();
        textBox3.AppendText(text);
        lr.Close();
    }
}
```

Как убрать .txt из переменной text в конце?

Comment: Приведите пример который воспроизводит  только проблему, не нужно приводить лишний код, в котором ни кто не будет разбиратся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, убрать что-то из переменной нельзя, более того, из строки, на которую она указывает -- тоже, можно создать новую строку и поместить ссылку на нее в переменную. Во-вторых, если я правильно понял, Вы хотите прочитать из конфига имя файла и убрать из него расширение, это делается так:

```
text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(text);
```

Чтобы использовать класс Path, Вам надо подключить пространство имен System.IO:

```
using System.IO;
```

Почитать про класс Path можно здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8

P.S. При использовании полученного значения в обработчике события Button1_Click, Вы приклеиваете расширение обратно, подумайте, действительно ли надо его убирать.

P.P.S. Для склеивания строк в данном случае стоит использовать не конкатенацию, а string.Format или, что еще лучше, интерполяцию строк, сравните с Вашим кодом:

```
File.AppendAllText(fn, $"────────────────────────\n\n{buf}\n{buf2}\n\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
var text = "abcdefgh.txt";
var tt = text.Remove(text.LastIndexOf('.'));
```